# HTML button copies to clipboard as line feed

Tags: html, css

Suppose that I have a `<table>` with 6 columns. In each row, column 4 either contains a `<button>` or nothing. Columns 1-3, 5-6 contain text.

Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/oq3uhhfe/

I would like to be able to highlight the table data in my browser window, copy it to the clipboard, and paste it into another application (Excel, Notepad, etc). However, the `<button>` appears to act as a line feed/break. For example, copy/pasting the table provided in the jsfiddle above gives me the following output:

```
One     Two     Three   
Five    Six
One     Two     Three       Five    Six
```

The bottom row works as I would like, but the top row does not. It does not appear as though adding an `&nbsp;` to the cell with the `<button>` helps, nor does applying the `-bla-user-select` styles to either the `<button>` or the `<td>`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Fiddle seems to work for me. Latest Chrome and Excel.

Comment: Also works fine for me with Chrome, Excel, and Notepad. What browser/application are you using?

Comment: Oh, wow. Yeah, Chrome seems to work for me, too. Latest Firefox and Excel, however, produce the problem.

Comment: PS. On android and chrome I get: OneTwoThreeClickFiveSixOneTwoThreeFiveSix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this just comes down to "different browsers behave differently."

To illustrate further, let me change the fiddle to use hidden buttons instead of an empty cell. I get radically different results between Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer:

https://jsfiddle.net/wxx70xu6/

Firefox pasted to Notepad:

```
One     Two     Three   
Five    Six
One     Two     Three       Five    Six
```

Chrome pasted to Notepad:

```
One Two Three   Click   Five    Six
One Two Three       Five    Six
```

Internet Explorer pasted to Notepad:

```
One Two Three Click  Five Six 
One Two Three   Five Six
```

Even more interesting is that Internet Explorer behaves differently in Excel than it does in Notepad. Notepad shows the above output, while Excel shows "Click" in both rows.

Thanks to those that replied.

**Edit:**
You can access the Clipboard through .NET with the [Clipboard class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx). The GetData method lets you retrieve the data in one of many formats.

When viewing the clipboard with the "text" format, the copied value looked like the output from Notepad (above).

Viewing the clipboard with the "html" format, which I'm assuming Excel uses, produces the following:

Internet Explorer

```
Version:1.0
StartHTML:000000203
EndHTML:000001132
StartFragment:000000740
EndFragment:000001084
StartSelection:000000760
EndSelection:000001074
SourceURL:https://fiddle.jshell.net/wxx70xu6/show/
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML><HEAD>
<SCRIPT src="/js/lib/dummy.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
             <LINK href="/css/result-light.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<STYLE type="text/css">
    table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
  </STYLE>
   <TITLE></TITLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){

}//]]>

</SCRIPT>
   </HEAD><BODY><TABLE><TBODY><!--StartFragment--><TR class="datarow"><TD>One</TD><TD>Two</TD><TD>Three</TD><TD><BUTTON name="clicker" type="button" value="Click">Click</BUTTON>     </TD><TD>Five</TD><TD>Six</TD></TR><TR class="datarow"><TD>One</TD><TD>Two</TD><TD>Three</TD><TD><BUTTON name="clicker" class="hidden" type="button" value="Click">Click</BUTTON>     <TD>Five</TD><TD>Six</TD></TR><!--EndFragment--></TBODY></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

Firefox

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:00000149
EndHTML:00000566
StartFragment:00000183
EndFragment:00000530
SourceURL:https://fiddle.jshell.net/wxx70xu6/show/
<html><body>
<!--StartFragment--><table><tbody><tr class="datarow"><td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td></td></tr></tbody></table><table><tbody><tr class="datarow"><td>Five</td>
    <td>Six</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="datarow">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>
    </td><td>Five</td>
    <td>Six</td></tr></tbody></table><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000157
EndHTML:0000001709
StartFragment:0000000193
EndFragment:0000001673
SourceURL:https://fiddle.jshell.net/wxx70xu6/show/
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><table style="border-collapse: collapse; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-size: medium; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial;"><tbody><tr class="datarow"><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">One</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">Two</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">Three</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;"><button name="clicker" type="button" value="Click">Click</button></td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">Five</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">Six</td></tr><tr class="datarow"><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">One</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">Two</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">Three</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;"></td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">Five</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); padding: 10px;">Six</td></tr></tbody></table><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```